# Is it safe to detect endianess with union?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, endianness, unions

In other words, according to the C **standard**, is this code safe? (Assume `uint8_t` is one byte)

```
void detectEndianness(void){
    union {
        uint16_t w;
        uint8_t b;
    } a;
    a.w = 0x00FFU;
    if (a.b == 0xFFU) {
        puts("Little endian.");
    }
    else if (a.b == 0U) {
        puts("Big endian.");
    }
    else {
        puts("Stack Overflow endian.");
    }
}
```

What if I change it into this? Note the third `if` case that I'm aware of.

```
a.w = 1U;
if (a.b == 1U) { puts("Little endian."); }
else if (a.b == 0U) { puts ("Big endian."); }
else if (a.b == 0x80U) { /* Special potential */ }
else { puts("Stack Overflow endian."); }
```

Comment: that sounds all right to me. but I'm not an adept of the C standard.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't handle middle-endian machines ;-) Though you need not test the endianness at runtime - you'd know that at compile time already.

Comment: What would be the use-case to detect it at run-time? Wouldn't a compiler macro be simpler?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What is "middle-endian"? Storing 0x0001 as `80 00`?

Comment: Middle-endian refers to multibyte layout that is neither little nor big endian. You cannot detect a middle-endian system with 2 bytes. They're not exactly common nowadays...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala there's no compile-time endian detection in Standard C

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that you usually should not care what the endianness is of your platform, and if you do, you're probably doing something wrong and could write endian-agnostic code instead. *Why* do you care?

Comment: @jamesdlin I know. I'm not going to write endianess-dependent code. I just want to know the safety of determining endianess like this.

Comment: Why do you need to? Very few useful things depend on endianness, most of them are handled by existing libraries.

Comment: @M.M of course there isn't. But depending on the implementation-level details like this is not strictly compliant either. On GCC the endianness can be detected from `__BYTE_ORDER__` which equals `__BIG_ENDIAN__`, `__LITTLE_ENDIAN__` or `__PDP_ENDIAN__`

Comment: It might be safe, but why does it matter? This is not the best method to determine endianness.

Comment: There are plenty of legitimate scenarios where needing to know the endianess is not a sign of bad design. E.g. receiving quantised numerical data over the wire. Reading any kind of packed binary format. Emscripten integration. We’re talking about C here. :S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from n1570:

[6.5.2.3 Structure and union members - p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p3)

> A postfix expression followed by the . operator and an identifier
>   designates a member of a structure or union object. **The value is that
>   of the named member**, and is an lvalue if the first expression is an
>   lvalue.

[6.2.6 Representations of types / 1 General - p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p7)

> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the
>   bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that
>   member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.

It's allowed. And your use case could even be considered one intended purpose, if [note 95](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note95) is taken into account (despite being only informative):

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the
>   same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the
>   appropriate part of the object representation of the value is
>   reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described
>   in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called "type punning"). This might be
>   a trap representation.

Now, since the uintN_t family of types are defined to have no padding bits

[7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types - p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1p2)

> The typedef name uintN_t designates an unsigned integer type with
>   width N and no padding bits. Thus, uint24_t denotes such an unsigned
>   integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits.

All their bit representations are valid values, no trap representations are possible. So we must conclude that it will indeed check for the endianess of `uint16_t`.

Comment: What might be a trap representation in the last sentence?

Comment: @iBug - [It's a bit representation that doesn't represent any valid value of the object](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19.4). For the integer types you use, there likely isn't one (I'm still looking for a reference, at the moment). Since each bit representation for them is usually a valid value.

Comment: Maybe you understood me wrongly. I know what a trap representation is but am unsure what may become a TR, as stated in the last sentenct.

Comment: If I'm not much mistaken, this has been changed with the introduction of strict aliasing rules. Which version of the standard are you citing from?

Comment: `uintN_t` types are defined with *"UINTN_MAX exactly 2^N − 1"* and no padding bits. There should be no trap presentation.

Comment: @cmaster - Strict aliasing (though never mentioned like that by name in the standard) predates this behavior of unions. Also note, there is no aliasing going on here. I read members, don't alias them.

Comment: @user694733 - Aha, thank you. You comment actually led me directly to the quote I needed

Comment: Well, the two members refer to the same bytes in memory, so they do alias each other... But if that paragraph is in the current standard, I guess that overrides the more generally formulated strict aliasing rules. So, +1 from me.

Comment: could you clarify why the compiler must place the objects in overlapping regions within the union boundary?

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b - That's the basic function of a union. The members overlap.

Comment: in former specs, the members "may" overlap.  I can't find anything stronger in this one. (Though it would be somewhat ridiculous if they didn't...but then again, we're already being pretty pedantic on this question... so a little more won't hurt)

Comment: My memory is apparently faulty.  that spec reads substantially like the one you cite.  I'll delete the earlier comment.  It would still be nice to find a prohibition on initial padding on all members of a union to make your answer air-tight.

Comment: The old 1999 spec comes close.  It prohibits initial padding on structs.

Comment: Hmm.  One of the undefined behaviors in J.2 is when "An object is assigned to an *inexactly overlapping* object", so overlap is not necessarily simple.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b - Not in general, no. In this particular case however, one can be fairly certain there is no undefined behavior. The quote presented by **greydet** bellow is a further guarantee. Since a pointer points at the first byte, and these objects overlap and have fixed width. There isn't wriggle room to sneak UB in.

Comment: well, "under suitable conversion" is important in that phrase, and greydet ignores it.  In the same sense that conversion is used here: http://c-faq.com/null/ptrtest.html.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b - Ah, but that's the crux of the matter. "suitably converted" is itself undefined (or at least, I could no find it). If the standard means it's merely a reinterpretation of the pointer value (my opinion), then there is nothing to worry about. If it includes value adjustment, we are in trouble. I consider it a wording defect. Because now that I think about it, not knowing the exact meaning here makes this question unanswerable. I think you should post the conclusions of this back and forth in an answer. It'd be good one.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b - On second thought, it also says *"A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member"*. Is it the same "suitably converted"? I'm starting to dislike this language lawyer question.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Because the Standard does not explicitly define the phrase "suitably converted", the most natural meaning would be "converted via any means defined by the Standard".  Such conversion need not imply simple reinterpretation of the bits, but the Standard offers no such reason the relation shouldn't be transitive.

Answer (score 1):

The standard (available in the linked online draft) says in a [footnote](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note95) that it is allowed to access a different member of the same union than the member previously written:

> 95) If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not
>   the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the
>   appropriate part of the object representation of the value is
>   reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described
>   in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ''type punning''). This might be
>   a trap representation.

But the footnote also mentions a possible trap representation, and the only data type that is guaranteed by the standard to be safe concerning trap representations is `unsigned char`. Accessing trap representations may be undefined behaviour; and although I don't think that `unit_32` may yield a trap representation on your platform, it is actually implementation dependant whether accessing this member is UB or not.

Comment: The uintNN_t types cannot have trap representations

Comment: @M.M Reference?

Comment: Read their specification in N1570

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that the order of bits within a byte match the ordering of the corresponding bits in a larger type.  A conforming implementation which defines `uint32_t` and has an 8-bit `unsigned char` could, for example, store the upper 16 bits of the uint32_t using four bits from each byte, and store the bottom 16 bits using the remaining four bits of each byte.  From the point of view of the Standard, any of 32! permutations of bits would be equally acceptable.

That having been said, any implementation that isn't being deliberately obtuse and is designed to run on a commonplace platform will use one of two orderings [treating bytes as groups of 8 consecutive bits, in the order 0123 or 3210], and one that doesn't use one of the above and targets any platform that isn't totally obscure will use 2301 or 1032.  The Standard doesn't forbid other orderings, but failure to accommodate them would be very unlikely to cause any trouble except when using obtusely-contrived implementations.

Comment: @M.M: The OP code would detect some weird orderings, but would leave many undetected.